# Image to fit screen in flexbox

Tags: image, flexbox, carousel, twitter-bootstrap-4

Bootstrap v4 beta 6 updated to use `display: flex` for its carousel items. now my `img` items end up stretching or moving about in new ways. my app is supposed to fit each image to the view screen. the basic idea is to have `max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;` so that the image is limited by the view but maintains correct proportions.

Does anybody have information on fitting a flexbox or its items to the screen? any help here is appreciated

here is my previous code that worked prior to the the flexbox update (srry that the ng-bootstrap directive leaves the flow vague)

**html**

```
<html><body>
<ngb-carousel id={{directory}}>
<template ngbSlide *ngFor="let what of whatList">
    <img class="mx-auto d-block" [src]=what>
</template>
</ngb-carousel>
</body></html>
```

**css**

```
html,body{height:100%;}
.carousel,.carousel-item,.active{height:100%;}
.carousel-inner{height:100%;}
img {
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This combination is *near* perfect:

**html**

```
<html><body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row"
<div class="col pl-0 pr-0"
  <ngb-carousel id={{directory}}>
  <template ngbSlide *ngFor="let what of whatList">
    <img class="mx-auto" [src]=what>
  </template>
  </ngb-carousel>
</div></div></div>
</body></html>
```

**css**

```
img {
  object-fit: contain;
  max-height:100vh;
  max-width:100%;
}
```